# Symfony3.1 : Unable to load css, js files and images on my application in production

Tags: symfony

I have deploy my Symfony 3.1 application and uploaded it online, following the symfony 3.1 cookbook steps (basic file transfer and common post-deployment tasks); I have checked all the requirements, install vendors, clear cache, and install all assets, but no images, css configurations nor js files are loading. I can only see the raw content.

any idea of what I can do?
thanks.

Comment: can you post how you did link your CSS and JS

Comment: Are you using apache? and what does your http.conf look like?

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a comment, cause have no reputation so I hope my advices will be like answer.

1. First solution very simple. Check the permissions of your web directory.

   ```
     chmod -R 0777 ./web
   ```
2. Check the config file (or post it's code here).
3. check if your paths are relative, something like:

   ```
   href="/images/myimage.jpg"
   ```

   Where images - folder which contains in web directory
4. And from my opinion try to clear cache once more in both dev and prod.